# Mongodb Populate is not populating document in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, typegoose

I am using typegoose and my `Query` and `QueryRule` models are as below.

```js
export class Query {
  @prop()
  queryRule: Ref<QueryRule>;
}
```

```js
export class QueryRule {
  @prop()
  condition: Condition;

  @prop()
  rules: Ref<QueryRule | ChildRule>[];
}
```

I am using the following query to populate.

```js
await QueryModel.findById(queryId).populate('queryRule');
```

My Query Document is as below.

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"6283d73baffa60c38af8c2f0"},"name":"test","queryRule":{"$oid":"6287c8f0e3ab4b5dd7238ef3"}}
```

My QueryRule Document is as below.

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"6287c8f0e3ab4b5dd7238ef3"},"condition":1,"rules":[],"__v":0}
```

But when I access `condition` and `rules` of QueryRule using populate query. I am getting undefined even though values exist in that document.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed 2 things for this.

1. First is I was missing `{ ref: () => QueryRule }`
2. Then in populate I had to pass model like this `{ path : 'queryRule', model: QueryRuleModel }`

```js
export class Query {
  @prop({ ref: () => QueryRule })
  queryRule: Ref<QueryRule>;
}
```

```js
let query: Query = await QueryModel
      .findById(queryId)
      .populate({ path : 'queryRule', model: QueryRuleModel });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that you are missing the required option `ref`, see [Reference other Classes](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/reference-other-classes) from the Typegoose Documentation.

In your case your code should look more like:

```
export class Query {
  @prop({ ref: () => QueryRule })
  queryRule: Ref<QueryRule>;
}

export class QueryRule {
  @prop()
  condition: Condition;

  //@prop({ ref: () => QueryRule })
  //rules: Ref<QueryRule | ChildRule>[];
}
```

As for `Ref<QueryRule | ChildRule>[]`, you will either have to limit it to one on the 2 possibilities or use discriminators, see [Non-Nested Discriminators](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/non-nested-discriminators) from the Typegoose Documentation.

Also as a small side-note, if your `condition: Condition` is not also a typegoose class, it will become `Mixed`, which is basically a `any` type at runtime in mongoose.

Comment: I am getting following error now.
`Schema hasn't been registered for model "QueryRule"`

Comment: Never mind. I have got it resolved. I have posted answer if you have any comment on that.

Answer (score -1):

```
@prop({
  ref: () => QueryRule | ChildRule,
  required: true
})
rules: Ref<QueryRule | ChildRule>[];
```

Comment: Getting this error with that => MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "QueryRule".

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This comment's answer is not correct javascript / typescript, `ref: () => QueryRule | ChildRule` is not valid, also as for typegoose, no unions are supported (or are working) unless discriminators are used